# How do i post variables inside a .js file to a php file without including jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm abit confused as to how i will go about doing this, so i'm making a .js file to collect data on a page(100% with js) and i want to POST it to a php file which will then take care of it and insert it into the db etc..

How will i go about doing this? I know you can use jquery in a html document, but i want to use it in a .js file not a .html file.

I've successfully done it using a .html file and importing the jquery file, but i want to do it all in a .js file.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you very much (:

Answer (score 1):

I'd comment, but I can't. Can you post some samples of your code?

What I got is that you are using JavaScript (jQuery) to POST (form data?) over to a PHP file. If you want to use jQuery inside of a `.js` file, all you have to do is include the jQuery library before you include your `.js` file, like so:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="myExternalScript.js"></script>
```

And then, inside of `myExternalScript.js`, you can use jQuery methods.

The external script is aware of your DOM elements, really, just like inline JavaScript would be, so you can still do whatever you want with your form or wherever you are getting the data to POST from.

**EDIT:** (in accordance to what you commented on this answer)

**EDIT 2:** I had forgotten to add the request header for POST

If you want to send an AJAX **POST** request (notice that I set the `Content-Type` request header, so that the data gets sent correctly):

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 

xmlhttp.open("POST","http://zegita.tk/stargazer/magic.php", true); 
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("n="+user);
```

If you want to send an AJAX **GET** request:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 

xmlhttp.open("GET","http://zegita.tk/stargazer/magic.php?n="+user, true); 

xmlhttp.send();
```

It is important that you use the correct method, depending on whether you are using `$_GET` or `$_POST` in your `magic.php` file.

Comment: I want to send people the .js file to put in there profiles, therefore i want the posting to happen inside the .js file.. it'll get the info it needs and post it to my php file which will insert it into the database. the info im getting is from cookies, not from forms, i want to get the username from a cookie, which i can get with no problem.. it's the posting to my php file to insert it into my db is the bit i don't understand.

Comment: Can you please post some code of what you have in your original post?

Comment: Hmm, try changing "GET" to "POST". If you want to use POST, yeah, you send your variables through send(), however, if you use GET, you add the parameters to the URL in open(). Like `"http://zegita.tk/stargazer/magic.php?n=" + user`, and don't place anything inside of send(). Also, open up the developer's console and see if the request is being sent on the network tab, or if there are any errors on the console.

Answer (score 0):

Clicking on the button runs this **SCRIPT** (which further passes 3 JS-variables to the **abc.php**)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function sendJSValsToPHP(){
        var xmlhttp;

        //These are the variables i am going to post to illustrate the example, what you want
        var var_1toPost = 1;
        var var_2toPost = 2;
        var var_3toPost = 3;

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
        else
          {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                //You can get the response text from abc.php file and process it in any of the tags you want by javascript code
                document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;              
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","abc.php?recieve_1="+var_1toPost+"&recieve_2="+var_2toPost+"&recieve_3="+var_3toPost,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

The echo'ed data in abc.php will come in the `div="myDiv" //as a response.`

```
<body>
    <div id="myDiv" style="border: 1px solid BLUE; height: 100px;">
        the things echo'ed in abc.php will come in this div
    </div>
    <button onclick="sendJSValsToPHP();">Click Me To Send JS-Values to abc.php</button>
</body>
```

and then in **abc.php** //file

```
<?php
    $recieved_1 = $_GET['recieve_1'];
    $recieved_2 = $_GET['recieve_2'];
    $recieved_3 = $_GET['recieve_3'];

    //Do your processing here and insert it in the database
        //Insert Query OR Update Query (whatever)
    // after you have inserted you can get the response in
    // the <div> having id="myDiv" Or whatever you want
    // Suppose you have successfully inserted data then 
    $insertedDataBoolean = true;
    if($insertedDataBoolean){
        echo "Data: " . $recieved_1 . ", " . $recieved_2 . 
        " and " . $recieved_3 . " inserted successfully.";
    }
    else{
        echo "Data-insertion error.";
    }
?>
```

Comment: No problem. Did it work properly in your case????? (it's a bit tricky, if  you don't understand: I am available. @КристинаСоколова ) :-)

Comment: I have updated the answer and the comments are illustrating the example how to send the variables to php file, how to recieve them in the php file.
Note that when the php file is called you still remain on the same page and the code runs inside the php file. @КристинаСоколова